# Change Default text and image of facebook like button

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

My android application implements Facebook using **Graph-Api** and shows Like button using **Social plugin** (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).Now i want to implement following changes.

1. Use **custom Like button** instead of **Facebook's traditional(standard,button_count,box_count) Like button**.
2. Change default text(**Like**)of Like button to **Like us on Facebook.**

   I am using **Html** having **javascript**, and **webview** to show Like button.**How can i achieve these changes**? **Is it possible to change the default text of like button**(Social plugin Like button).Is there any problem if we alter traditional components of Facebook(ie,changing text,changing image etc...)?

Answer (score 1):

1) You cannot make your own custom Like button, in the [brand permissions page](https://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php) it says under the Facebook Like Button section:

> While you may scale the size to suit your needs, you may not modify the Like Button in any other way (such as by changing the design).

2) Same as above, you cannot modify the like button in any way.

Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: It only says you can't modify their button... I think you'd be ok with a custom button as long as it bore absolutely NO resemblance to the official 'like' button... maybe pink with no thumbs-up or 'F' on it...